# I have problem with my homework - join shows no data

Tags: sql, oracle

It's me again - I have a new homework and I don't get any further.

The task is:

*Find out the date of flight(DATE_FLY), flight number(FLY_NR), manufacturer(MANUF), type (TYP) and serial number (SER_NR) of all flights that fly from Frankfurt to Dallas between 10.11.2013 and 20.11.2013.*

This is the `departure_table`:

| DATE_FLY | FLY_NR | MANUF | TYP | PER_NR | SER_NR | TIME_START |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06.07.13 | LH-888 | Boeing | B747 | 9fg-he-ztu8 | 10010071 | 11.23 |
| 08.10.13 | LH-238 | Airbus | A320 | z3et-bwe7 | 10010072 | 22.06 |
| 13.11.13 | LH-341 | Boeing | B737 | ba23-0012 | 10010001 | 10.23 |
| 14.11.13 | LH-358 | Boeing | B737 | ba23-0012 | 10010001 | 8.17 |
| 13.11.13 | LH-553 | Boeing | B777 | xv23-0889 | 10010002 | 16.53 |
| 15.11.13 | LH-421 | Boeing | B777 | xv56-3142 | 10010002 | 14.45 |
| 17.11.13 | LH-789 | Airbus | A330 | 45-6789 | 10010003 | 8.11 |
| 14.11.13 | LH-112 | Boeing | B737 | ba23-0034 | 10010001 | 8.14 |
| 17.11.13 | LH-421 | Boeing | B777 | xv23-0889 | 10010002 | 16.26 |
| 18.11.13 | LH-223 | Airbus | A380 | ab-45-6xf | 10010004 | 9.45 |
| 19.11.13 | LH-634 | Airbus | A350 | 5478-awe3 | 10010005 | 20.25 |
| 18.02.14 | LH-238 | Airbus | A320 | z3et-bwe7 | 10010072 | 23.06 |

And this is the `fly_table` that I need to join:

| FLY_NR | START_FLY | DEST_FLY | TIME_FLY | KM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LH-341 | Saarbruecken | Hamburg | 1.2 | 490 |
| LH-358 | Saarbruecken | Leipzig | 1.1 | 430 |
| LH-553 | Leipzig | Hamburg | .5 | 290 |
| LH-112 | Luxemburg | London | 1.1 | 480 |
| LH-421 | Luxemburg | Ankara | 2.5 | 2300 |
| LH-789 | Luxemburg | New-York | 3.5 | 8300 |
| LH-223 | Frankfurt | Dallas | 3.9 | 8600 |
| LH-634 | Frankfurt | Moskau | 2.3 | 2020 |
| LH-888 | Frankfurt | Peking | 9.5 | 7780 |
| LH-238 | Muenchen | Berlin | 1.1 | 479 |

I wrote the following query but it showed me "no data found":

```
select 
    dp.date_fly, dp.fly_nr, dp.manuf, dp.typ, dp.ser_nr
from
    departure_table dp, fly_table fl
where 
    dp.fly_nr = fl.fly_nr
    and start_fly = 'Frankfurt'
    and dest_fly = 'Dallas'
    and dp.date_fly between 10.11.2013 and 20.11.2013;
```

I've tried a simple join but I still only got the message "no data found":

```
select 
    dp.date_fly, dp.fly_nr, dp.manuf, dp.typ, dp.ser_nr
from 
    departure_table dp, fly_table fl
where 
    dp.fly_nr = fl.fly_nr;
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong... I would be very thankful if somebody could help to solve this problem with the join function.

I need to get this result:

| DATE_FLY | FLY_NR | MANUF | TYP | SER_NR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-NOV-13 | LH-223 | Airbus | A380 | 10010004 |

Thank you!

Comment: Do you see anything from [select  * from departure_table] or [select * from fly_table]? Also, change to contemporary join syntax [..from departure_table dp join fly_table fl on dp.fly_nr = fl.fly_nr ]. Also, you should mark the ACCEPT flag on your answered questions.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Which operating system is running this query? From my understanding there could be case-sensitive issues by operating system. Normally this isn't a problem if you're running on Windows, but Linux on the other hand is case sensitive. Try changing the column name and table name to uppercase.

Comment: @Isolated Oracle is not case sensitive unless you are using quoted identifiers; the OP's query does not use quoted identifiers and if it did and the case was wrong then the query would raise an exception (rather than running and returning zero rows).

Comment: Your query returns an error `ORA-00905: missing keyword` as `between 10.11.2013 and 20.11.2013` is invalid syntax. If you change it to `between DATE '2013-11-10' and DATE '2013-11-20';` then your query works and returns a single row [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tLd1Z2NR)

Comment: @MT0: Thank you! The column FLY_DATE has a VARCHAR2 format, so it doesn't with your option between DATE... and DATE. When I use  ...and dp.date_fly between 10.11.2013 and 20.11.2013; I still get the message no data found. How do I get this result:
| 18.11.13  | LH-223 | Airbus | A380 | 10010004 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The column `FLY_DATE` has a `VARCHAR2` format

This is bad practice. If you have a date then store it as a date. If you have to store it as a string (really, don't do that) then store it using ISO8601 formatting `YYYY-MM-DD` which can be sorted alphabetically into date-order (and not `DD-MM-YYYY` which cannot be easily sorted).

Since you have it in a (mostly unusable) string format, you need to convert it to a `DATE` using the `TO_DATE` function and compare it to `DATE` literals:

```sql
select dp.date_fly,
       dp.fly_nr,
       dp.manuf,
       dp.typ,
       dp.ser_nr
from   departure_table dp
       INNER JOIN fly_table fl
       ON dp.fly_nr = fl.fly_nr
where  start_fly = 'Frankfurt'
and    dest_fly = 'Dallas'
and    TO_DATE(dp.date_fly, 'DD.MM.YYYY') between DATE '2013-11-10' and DATE '2013-11-20';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE departure_table (DATE_FLY, FLY_NR, MANUF, TYP, PER_NR, SER_NR, TIME_START) AS
SELECT '06.07.2013', 'LH-888', 'Boeing', 'B747', '9fg-he-ztu8', 10010071, 11.23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '08.10.2013', 'LH-238', 'Airbus', 'A320', 'z3et-bwe7',   10010072, 22.06 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '13.11.2013', 'LH-341', 'Boeing', 'B737', 'ba23-0012',   10010001, 10.23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14.11.2013', 'LH-358', 'Boeing', 'B737', 'ba23-0012',   10010001,  8.17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '13.11.2013', 'LH-553', 'Boeing', 'B777', 'xv23-0889',   10010002, 16.53 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '15.11.2013', 'LH-421', 'Boeing', 'B777', 'xv56-3142',   10010002, 14.45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '17.11.2013', 'LH-789', 'Airbus', 'A330', '45-6789',     10010003,  8.11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14.11.2013', 'LH-112', 'Boeing', 'B737', 'ba23-0034',   10010001,  8.14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '17.11.2013', 'LH-421', 'Boeing', 'B777', 'xv23-0889',   10010002, 16.26 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '18.11.2013', 'LH-223', 'Airbus', 'A380', 'ab-45-6xf',   10010004,  9.45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '19.11.2013', 'LH-634', 'Airbus', 'A350', '5478-awe3',   10010005, 20.25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '18.02.2014', 'LH-238', 'Airbus', 'A320', 'z3et-bwe7',   10010072, 23.06 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE fly_table (FLY_NR, START_FLY, DEST_FLY, TIME_FLY, KM) AS
SELECT 'LH-341', 'Saarbruecken', 'Hamburg',  1.2,  490 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-358', 'Saarbruecken', 'Leipzig',  1.1,  430 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-553', 'Leipzig',      'Hamburg',   .5,  290 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-112', 'Luxemburg',    'London',   1.1,  480 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-421', 'Luxemburg',    'Ankara',   2.5, 2300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-789', 'Luxemburg',    'New-York', 3.5, 8300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-223', 'Frankfurt',    'Dallas',   3.9, 8600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-634', 'Frankfurt',    'Moskau',   2.3, 2020 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-888', 'Frankfurt',    'Peking',   9.5, 7780 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LH-238', 'Muenchen',     'Berlin',   1.1,  479 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DATE_FLY | FLY_NR | MANUF | TYP | SER_NR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18.11.2013 | LH-223 | Airbus | A380 | 10010004 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DQhYg3Ai)

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!  This was the task in our homework -  the tables were prepared like this from our teacher. But thank you for your time - I have learned a lot!!

Comment: @DonDon The first lesson should be to always use appropriate data types. The second lesson is that sometimes teachers don't teach the correct things.